# Date picker not saving to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Problems with wiring up datepicker

The code for partial view

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yy"), new { @class = "date" })
```

The code for the view

```
 @Html.TextBox("DateTime", (Model.AdvertStartDate.ToString()), new { @class = "date" })
```

Scripts

```
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Code used for datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker
        ({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            showStatus: true,
            showWeeks: true,
            currentText: 'Now',
            autoSize: true,
            gotoCurrent: true,
            showAnim: 'blind',
            highlightWeek: true

        });
    });
</script>
```

Code for model

```
 [Required]
   public DateTime AdvertStartDate { get; set; }
```

The date is inserting into the textbox but is not updating in the database

Can you suggest anything that is missing?

Comment: try selecting this date "1/1/2012" while saving, does this too not work, I think I know the problem, but you try this out first and let me know

Comment: hmmm, ok how are you saving the date filled ?

Comment: Would need to see the controller POST action for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the HTML `<input>` element rendered by `TextBox("DateTime",...)` doesn't have the correct name (the name will be "DateTime"), so it doesn't get bound correctly to your model property `AdvertStartDate` when the data are posted to the server.

Your "partial view" looks like an EditorTemplate to me. In this case you should be able to just use this in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdvertStartDate)
```

Because `AdvertStartDate` is of type `DateTime` the EditorTemplate including the DatePicker should be used to render the input element.

If the EditorTemplate file has another name than `DateTime.cshtml` - like `AnotherTemplateName.cshtml` - you can specify the template explicitly:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdvertStartDate, "AnotherTemplateName")
```

Answer (score 0):

Datapicker is not the easy element to implement in MVC application.

Try condsider next things:

1. Make sure that data from data picker is sent to server (datapicker should have appropriate name)
2. Make sure that datapicker dataformat is the same as your application data format (which can differ depanding on chosen culture) - in that case data is sent to server, but not always valid because 31.01 get be transated as month 31, date 1.